# My Programming Lab standard output errors

Tags: java, output, system

I've been working on this code and everything seems to be working, but when MyProgrammingLab actually runs my code it says there is a problem with my standard output.

**Here is the problem:**

Write a Temperature class  that will hold a temperature in Fahrenheit and provide methods  to get the temperature in Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Kelvin. The class  should have the
following field:

• ftemp: a double  that holds a Fahrenheit temperature.

The class  should have the following methods :

• Constructor : The constructor  accepts a Fahrenheit temperature (as a double ) and stores  it in the ftemp field.
• setFahrenheit: The set Fahrenheit method  accepts a Fahrenheit temperature (as a double ) and stores  it in the ftemp field.
• getFahrenheit: Returns the value  of the ftemp field as a Fahrenheit temperature (no conversion  required)
• getCelsius: Returns the value  of the ftemp field converted to Celsius. Use the following formula to convert to Celsius:
Celsius = (5/9) * (Fahrenheit - 32)
• getKelvin: Returns the value  of the ftemp field converted to Kelvin. Use the following formula to convert to Kelvin:
Kelvin = ((5/9) * (Fahrenheit - 32)) + 273

Demonstrate the Temperature class  by writing a separate program  that asks the user for a 
Fahrenheit temperature. The program  should create an instance of the Temperature class ,
with the value  entered by the user passed to the constructor . The program  should then
call the object 's methods  to display the temperature in the following format (for example,
if the temperature in Fahrenheit was -40):

The temperature in Fahrenheit is -40.0
The temperature in Celsius is -40.0
The temperature in Kelvin is 233.0

**And now here is my code:**

```html
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Temperature
{
 private double ftemp;
 
 public Temperature(double ftemp)
 {
  this.ftemp = ftemp;
 }
 public void setFahrenheit(double ftemp)
 {
  this.ftemp = ftemp;
 }
 public double getFahrenheit()
 {
  return ftemp;
 }
 public double getCelsius()
 {
  return (5.0/9.0) * (ftemp - 32.0);
 }
 public double getKelvin()
 {
  return (5.0/9.0) * ((ftemp - 32.0) + 273.0);
 }
}


class myTemperature
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  double input;
  
  System.out.print("Enter a Fahrenheit temperature:");
  
  input = keyboard.nextDouble();
  
  Temperature temp1 = new Temperature(input);
  
  System.out.println("The temperature in Fahrenheit is " + temp1.getFahrenheit());
  System.out.println("The temperature in Celsius is " + temp1.getCelsius());
  System.out.println("The temperature in Kelvin is " + temp1.getKelvin());
 }
}
```

**These are the errors it gives me:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNCpw.png

I don't have enough rep to post images, sorry!

I really just don't understand what the problem could be, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, while that wasn't part of my initial problem, after I figured out the main bit, that did show up as an error in  my logic and I did fix it :)

Comment: The main problem I had was that even though my System.out code was correct, it was not printing anything and I didn't understand why. But then I realized that you can only have one public class in your code so all I had to do was just delete the class myTemperature line and adjust the braces, and boom, problem solved! I was so used to writing my class and class tests in different project files that I didn't realize the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public double getKelvin()
{
    return ((5.0/9.0) * (ftemp - 32.0)) + 273.0;
}
```

Note the changes in ()